# APGL (Another Python Graph Library) testing error after installation

Tags: python, graph, io, installation

Did anyone successfully install apgl graph library for python? http://packages.python.org/apgl/ Is there other alternative graph libraries in python that does the same stuff as apgl with the same simplicity?

Currently i'm using Ubuntu 12.04 distro and i've installed the dependent libraries here:

```
sudo apt-get install pip
sudo pip install numpy
sudo apt-get install libatlas-base-dev gfortran g++
sudo pip install scipy
sudo pip install matplotlib
sudo pip install agpl
```

It installed successfully,then when i did:

```
>>> import apgl
>>> apgl.test()
```

I encounter the error:

```
>>> apgl.test()
Running tests from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apgl
..............s....................................................E...........E.................................................ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss.....................................................................E.........E.........................................sssssssss...sssssss..sssssssssssssssssssssssssssss.................................s....s..ss..........
======================================================================
ERROR: testLoad (graph.test.SparseGraphTest.SparseGraphTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apgl/graph/test/MatrixGraphTest.py", line 1619, in testLoad
    graph.save(tempFile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apgl/graph/AbstractMatrixGraph.py", line 558, in save
    import zipfile
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py", line 464, in <module>
    class ZipExtFile(io.BufferedIOBase):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'BufferedIOBase'

======================================================================
ERROR: testPickle (graph.test.SparseGraphTest.SparseGraphTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apgl/graph/test/MatrixGraphTest.py", line 2309, in testPickle
    output = pickle.dumps(graph)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1374, in dumps
    Pickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 224, in dump
    self.save(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 306, in save
    rv = reduce(self.proto)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/copy_reg.py", line 84, in _reduce_ex
    dict = getstate()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apgl/graph/AbstractMatrixGraph.py", line 1287, in __getstate__
    self.save(tempFile.name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apgl/graph/AbstractMatrixGraph.py", line 558, in save
    import zipfile
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py", line 464, in <module>
    class ZipExtFile(io.BufferedIOBase):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'BufferedIOBase'

======================================================================
ERROR: testLoad (graph.test.DenseGraphTest.DenseGraphTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apgl/graph/test/MatrixGraphTest.py", line 1619, in testLoad
    graph.save(tempFile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apgl/graph/AbstractMatrixGraph.py", line 558, in save
    import zipfile
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py", line 464, in <module>
    class ZipExtFile(io.BufferedIOBase):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'BufferedIOBase'

======================================================================
ERROR: testPickle (graph.test.DenseGraphTest.DenseGraphTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apgl/graph/test/MatrixGraphTest.py", line 2309, in testPickle
    output = pickle.dumps(graph)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1374, in dumps
    Pickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 224, in dump
    self.save(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 306, in save
    rv = reduce(self.proto)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/copy_reg.py", line 84, in _reduce_ex
    dict = getstate()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apgl/graph/AbstractMatrixGraph.py", line 1287, in __getstate__
    self.save(tempFile.name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apgl/graph/AbstractMatrixGraph.py", line 558, in save
    import zipfile
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py", line 464, in <module>
    class ZipExtFile(io.BufferedIOBase):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'BufferedIOBase'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 423 tests in 46.433s

FAILED (errors=4, skipped=120)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me you have some kind of an Ubuntu problem.

```
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py", line 464, in <module>
   class ZipExtFile(io.BufferedIOBase):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'BufferedIOBase'
```

Indicates that something is wrong with your python installation.

Did you install it your self?

Plus ... while pip is great, you should prefer to work with you package manager, and only if you *must* install really new versions or non-packaged versions you should use pip. Hence instead of installing with pip do,

```
apt-get install python-scipy python-numpy python-matplotlib
```

And only then install apgl with pip.

I tested my installation apgl successfully on a Debian Wheezy with packages updated as of today (13-Sep-2012), and the test results are fine.

```
 In [22]: apgl.test()
Running tests from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apgl
......./usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/compressed.py:486: SparseEfficiencyWarning: changing the sparsity structure of a csr_matrix is expensive. lil_matrix is more efficient.
  SparseEfficiencyWarning)
....s...........................................................................................ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss...................................................................................................................................................sssssssss...ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss......................s....s.........................ss
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 423 tests in 25.454s

OK (skipped=120)
```

Comment: nope not working, i thought python2.7 was installed wrongly so i did `sudo apt-get remove python2.7` And now the whole OS isn't working.. i have to reinstall my ubuntu...

Comment: Never ever ever deinstall Python on Linux distros! it is an essential competent of the system. I am surprised Ubuntu didn't warn you. Oh, well, if you already re-install, consider Debian, it is the same but better in many ways.

Comment: @2er0, so you installed your Ubuntu again, than installed numpy and scipy from apt-get and it worked?

Comment: yep, now it works, python has nothing to do with the problem. These are my steps to get eclipse, pylucene, pydev, numpy, scipy, matplotlib, networkx to work on python. 
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1UXd6gFjCSHHsTt6K2jhPx2IHY19K9fknHLBmkV-V9o4/edit
Now i'm just using networkx instead of apgl, it does the same thing but with a larger community.

Comment: @2er0, you are still doing in a very very weired way. What is the reason you install numpy and scipy from pip? do you really need the latest version?

Comment: sort of =), i know i've been alternating between apt-get and pip. but at the end, i manage to make it work.